# Octave fminunc doesn't update

Tags: octave

I have the following octave script:

```
clear;

T0 = [...
    1.0, 1.0, 5.0; ...
    1.0, 2.0, 3.0; ...
    -1.0,0.0, 6.0];

option = optimset('Display','Iter','GradObj','on','MaxIter','300','TolFun',10-5);
[t f] = fminunc(@flatTriangle,T0(:),option);

t = reshape(t,3,3);
```

And following octave functions

```
function [cost grad] = flatTriangle(T)
  T = reshape(T,3,3);

  Q = T(1,:)';
  P = T(2,:)';
  R = T(3,:)';

  e3 = [0;0;1];

  nf = cross(R - Q,P - Q);

  cost = 0.5*(e3'*nf - norm(nf))^2;

  grad = zeros(9,1);

  commonStuff = (e3'*nf - norm(nf))*(e3 - nf/norm(nf))';

  grad(1:3) = (commonStuff*skew(P - R)')';
  grad(4:6) = (commonStuff*skew(R - Q)')';
  grad(7:9) = (commonStuff*skew(Q - P)')';

endfunction

function Vhat = skew(V)
  Vhat = [...
   0.0 -V(3) V(2); ...
   V(3) 0.0 -V(1); ...
   -V(2) V(1) 0.0];
endfunction
```

Now despite the fact the grad vector isn't 0 the final output doesn't change at all from the initial input.

Am I using incorrectly something? maybe I'm not configuring something properly?
The code runs but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: TolFun is 10-5 = 5 which is very high and very unlikely that this is wanted

Comment: And there seems to be an issue with your gradient calculation. You can remove the GradObj on option as test which shows the minimized result.

Comment: I can spot the issue with my gradient. I debugged it and it isn't 0. The error tol is clearly wrong, I'll fix it later

Comment: So you can close this question?

Comment: No, because I don't get what am I doing wrong, except for the error tol, but I changed it and still I can't see any difference.

Comment: but you have also a problem with your gradient, `fminunc` returns an error -3 if you call it with `[t f info] = fminunc...` as soon as you remove the gradient and let it compute internally fminunc works as expected (as I already tried to tell you in my second comment)